# ajax cross origin request doesn't work in safari but works in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, xmlhttprequest, cors

I'm making a shopify app that uses script tags and I need to make an ajax call to our server to get the information needed about the shop. Everything was working great until my colleague made me notice that it wasn't working at all on his iphone. It's also not working in safari on mac but it works in chrome.

I noticed that the status of the request is always "0" in safari and I tried to make a request to the test shop I'm doing my tests instead of our server and got a 200 status. So now I'm pretty sure it's a cross origin problem.

From what I found it should be the headers that I need to change on the requested page but I already had "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" and I tried all the suggestion I could find and nothing works.

currently this is what I have on the requested page, I'm using laravel:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

$shop = Shop::where("domain", request('shop'))->first();

echo json_encode(
[ 
    'logo' => $shop->logo, 
    'text' => $shop->customizable_text, 
    'version' => $shop['plan'] 
]);
```

and this is the function I'm currently using to make the call in javascript(I was using jquery at first but I thought it was the problem so I tried with only javascript):

```
function ajaxRequest(url, parameters, callback){
const req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
    // XMLHttpRequest.DONE === 4
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            callback(this.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("Status: %d (%s)", this.status, this.statusText);
        }
    }
};

if(parameters.keys.length){
    url = url + "?"
    for(var i = 0; i < parameters.param.length; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            url = url + parameters.keys[i] + "=" + parameters.param[i]
        }
        else{
            url = url + "&" + parameters.keys[i] + "=" + parameters.param[i];
        }
    }
}

req.open('GET', url, true);
req.send(null);
}
```

everything works like it should in chrome and firefox, it's just safari. Any idea what I should do to fix this?

Comment: You probably want to use https://stackoverflow.com/q/47166384/441757 to edit/update your question and add the exact error messages (if any) that you’re seeing in the Safari devtools console. Also it would help if you go to the Network tab in Safari devtools and reload and check the details of all the relevant requests and responses there, including the HTTP status codes and HTTP methods and all the headers, and add those to the question too

Comment: @sideshowbarker I don't have access to a mac, but I managed to debug using remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter with an iphone and there's no error. I only see the console log "Status: 0". in the network tab I don't see my ajax call, it's like it's not called at all(but it works if I change the url to the same domain I'm doing my tests).

Answer (score 0):

Try allowing all headers to check it out you are missing any header

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

Answer (score 0):

like always it was a stupid mistake. I forgot to put the 's' to 'https'. safari don't even try to send the request if you make the request to a http url from an https website.